# hyperlink the pre-label instead of only the number

Tags: hyperref, ref

I'm trying to get the "Figure 1" in hyperlink and not only the number.

I tried to use `\ref` and `\nameref` but it appear only the `1` or the full caption instead of `figure 1` only

in example:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{table.png}
\caption{A typical home and business products-comparison table}
\label{fig:comparison_table}
\end{figure}
```

the `\ref{fig:comparison_table} ...`

It appear like:

[image]

or, if I use the `\nameref{fig:comparison_table}`

It appear like:

[image]

Comment: You could have a look at the `cleveref` package and its `\cref` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `hyperref`, `\autoref` is available for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  Content
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{label}
\end{figure}
\autoref{label}
\end{document}
```

[image]